What is the difference between 表演 and 演出?
Dictionary translate :
表演 : perform, act, play, demonstrate
演出 : perform, put on a show, performance
both could as verb and noun.
are they could use interchangeably ?


Could they be used interchangeably?

Only "performance" is interchangeable
鋼琴表演 piano performance (O)
鋼琴演出 piano performance (O)

演出默劇 play mime (O)

表演默劇 Performs mime (X)

表演魔術 Performs magic (O)

演出魔術 play magic (X)

表演胸口碎大石 Performs breaking stone on the chest (O)

演出胸口碎大石 play breaking stone on the chest (X)

~~~~~~~~~~

Basically:

演出 = play; 表演 = performs/show/ demonstrate 

演出/ 表演 = performance

Note: "鋼琴演奏" is a more common way to describe piano performance than 鋼琴演出


表演默剧是可以的吧，反正我的语感认为这可以

演默剧 would be natural, not 表演默剧. 表演 doesn't express the meaning of 'playing a character/role'

playing the character - "出演"?

出演 sounds so Japanese. However, I do think sentences like "由周潤發出演(= 飾演)許文強" are comprehensible by the general public because Chinese and Japanese have been influencing each other to this days
